# Remove date from wordpress images?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I upload images in Wordpress I get:

```
http://test.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/test_image.jpg
```

however I would like it like this:

```
http://test.net/wp-content/uploads/test_image.jpg
```

See how the date isn't in the URL on the 2nd one? Anyways, is that possible? To remove the date stamp from the Image URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Log into your WP admin, and go to `Settings > Media` and make sure the "Organize my files into month- and year-based folders" option is **not** checked.

On the same settings page, you can change the default upload folder altogether.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't see Miscellaneous anywhere... wait it's elsewhere. Heh.

Comment: For older versions, I think it was `Settings > Media`.

Comment: But how to remove date from existing media(I mean already uploaded images still show date)